# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKitCore"

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

Ive been getting error below while running `pod install`.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKitCore":
  In Podfile:
    PhoneNumberKit (from `https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit`) was resolved to 3.6.5, which depends on
      PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKitCore (= 3.6.5)
    flutter_libphonenumber_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_libphonenumber_ios/ios`) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKitCore (= 3.6.0)
Specs satisfying the `PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKitCore (= 3.6.0), PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKitCore (= 3.6.5)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I've tried increasing the minimum deployment target as recommended but none of the versions seem to solve the issue.
my current deployment target is `12.0`.
I've also deleted my `Podfile.lock` and pod install once again but it still failed.
I've also run `pod repo update` but no success.

I've run `flutter clean` and got dependencies once again and still none of these seem to work.

I'm also running the latest version of `flutter_libphonenumber: 2.1.4`.

Comment: I hate it when this happens, I usually delete the entire ios folder and create it again using flutter create. Remember to backup your existing ios folder.

Answer (score 3):

After trying out all mentioned options and failing surely, I finally figured out a temporary solution.
The issue is arising from the github repo provided added to the Podfile:

```
pod 'PhoneNumberKit', :git => 'https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit'
```

This is provided by the `flutter_libphonenumber: 2.1.4` documentation in the install instructions for ios.
The repo however introduced a new release `3.6.5` whereas the package only supoports `3.6.0`.

To provide the required support I created a repository containing the source files for `3.6.0` https://github.com/BTonny/PhoneNumberKit-3.6.0

So i go ahead and add that instead to my Podfile

```
pod 'PhoneNumberKit', :git => 'https://github.com/BTonny/PhoneNumberKit-3.6.0'
```

That solved the dependency issue for me temporarily and I hope the `flutter_libphonenumber` team will have that resolved eventually then we can revert.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's not necessary to create a own repo with the reverted changes. Just add the tag info in the Podfile:
pod "PhoneNumberKit", :git => "https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit", :tag => '3.6.0'
Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for this insight. I had tried using the complete tree url (https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit/tree/3.6.0) and it didn't work, so that's why i had resorted to that. Let me try this approach out and then hope it works. That is a much better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed the version of phone_number dependency in the pubspec.yaml file and it started working.
phone_number: ^1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solution for this issue

**Solution 1:**

add this line in at the top in your podfile inside ios folder:

```
# pod 'PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKitCore', :git => 'https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit', :tag => '3.5.10'
```

**Solution 2:**

or change the dependency to

```
phone_number: ^1.0.0
```